# How to return an even distribution of values between two indices in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, loops

How do you efficiently return `nan's` with an even distribution of values between indices? I have done this manually through a slice but this becomes very inefficient when you have 1000's of call to make.

This question is probably easier to understand via a desired input/output than text.

An example `df` is displayed below which contains random `nan's` throughout:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), 
                  index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                  columns=['one', 'two'])

df = df.mask(np.random.random(df.shape) < .5)
ix = [(row, col) for row in range(df.shape[0]) for col in range(df.shape[1])]
for row, col in random.sample(ix, int(round(.1*len(ix)))):
df.iat[row, col] = np.nan
```

While the function is random it will produce something like is:

```
         one       two
1        NaN       NaN
2   0.823711 -1.581639
3        NaN -1.632728
4   2.267315 -1.213950
5        NaN -0.779525
6        NaN       NaN
7        NaN -1.817710
8   0.190799       NaN
9        NaN       NaN
10       NaN       NaN
```

If we consider `column one`, I'd like to insert values into rows 3,5,6,7,9. I can do this manually by slicing the column and row. So if I wanted to find index 3 I would add 2.267315 and 0.823711 and divide by 3. This is an easy one as it is just the mean. Which would equal 1.545513. However, I have some nan's which are spread out over multiple indices, e.g 5,6,7. If I wanted to find 5,6,7 I would minus 2.267315 and 0.19079 and divide by 4.

So the expected output would be:

```
             one       two
    1        NaN       NaN
    2   0.823711 -1.581639
    3   1.545513 -1.632728
    4   2.267315 -1.213950
    5   1.748247 -0.779525
    6   1.229057 -1.298525
    7   0.709928 -1.817710
    8   0.190799       NaN
    9        NaN       NaN
    10       NaN       NaN
```

I started to manually do this by slicing between each appropriate row. Apart from this I considered a loop, but each calculation will be different because the nan's are randomly spread throughout the dataset. They also fluctuate to be greater or smaller than the previous number.

Comment: Sorry @jezrael, I was editing the question. An example output is shown. As stated in the question I'm struggling to describe it. I'm hoping to find the "incremental mean" if that makes sense. So `3` index would be in the middle of `2` and `4`. `5`,`6`,`7` would be split evenly between `4` and `8`. So in increments of 0.51913125. If there were 6 `nan's` between `4` and `8` that average increment would be smaller.

Comment: 5 = 1.748247, 6 = 1.229057, 7 = 0.709928. With your output 5,6,7 would all = 1.229057.

Comment: The above df is just an example. Some nan's go for 10 indices in a row. Basically, if there's more than one nan in a row the true mean is undesirable. I'l like the nan's to be replaced by an even distribution between the two appropriate values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`interpolate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) with omit last `NaN`s by [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.bfill().notnull(), df.interpolate())
print (df)
         one       two
1        NaN       NaN
2   0.823711 -1.581639
3   1.545513 -1.632728
4   2.267315 -1.213950
5   1.748186 -0.779525
6   1.229057 -1.298617
7   0.709928 -1.817710
8   0.190799       NaN
9        NaN       NaN
10       NaN       NaN
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.interpolate())
         one       two
1        NaN       NaN
2   0.823711 -1.581639
3   1.545513 -1.632728
4   2.267315 -1.213950
5   1.748186 -0.779525
6   1.229057 -1.298617
7   0.709928 -1.817710
8   0.190799 -1.817710
9   0.190799 -1.817710
10  0.190799 -1.817710
```

Comment: Just edited the question to display an intended output @jezrael. The `nan's` are of random length so I was hoping to not have a hard coded divisible number.

Comment: @Punter345 - It seems you need interpolate, please check edited answer.